# How to Use jQuery .each() to Create a JSON Array or Object

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object, each

I've seen a lot of examples that site how to use jQuery and .each() to parse json arrays.  What I want to do is use the .each() function to create the json.  I'm getting input from the user regarding text boxes that will be used in an ajax call to sort a table.  I am using .each() to find all text boxes that have valid input, and then I want to put that data into a json data type and send it via ajax to an SQL query.  I'm not certain if I want an object vs. an array, and from what data I've parsed thus far, my object doesn't seem to contain everything I'd expect.

I've created a global object to store the data, but a previous post on the web shows brackets, when everything I've seen for an array is parens ( ), and an object is curly braces { }.  So my global 'object' (since I don't know what to call [ ]) at this point looks like this:

```
var jsonFilter = [];
```

For the .each() function, that looks at user data 'onkeyup' to filter the list:

```
$("input:text[id^='filter']").live({
        focusin: function () {
            currentFilter = $(this).val();
            $(this).removeClass("filter");
            $(this).val("");
        },

        focusout: function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                // If they gave up focus and didn't type anything in the box, restore the text
                $(this).addClass("filter");
                $(this).val(currentFilter);
            }
        },

        keyup: function () {
            $("input:text[id^='filter']").each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() != "" && !$(this).hasClass('filter')) {
                    //alert("filterBy: " + $(this).attr('id') + "\nfilterValue: " + $(this).val());
                    jsonFilter.push({ filterBy: $(this).attr('id'), filterValue: $(this).val() });
                }
            });
            //alert("Done with .each()");
            filterReport(jsonFilter);
        }
    });
```

And for the array that is outputting the content of the jsonFilter:

```
function filterReport(_jsonFilter) {
        $("#jsonFilterLength").html(_jsonFilter.length);
        //$("#filterTest").html("");
        for (var i = 0; i < _jsonFilter.length; i++) {
            $("#filterTest").append("Index: " + i + ", filterBy: " + _jsonFilter[i]["filterBy"] + ", filterValue: " + _jsonFilter[i]["filterValue"] + "<br /><br />");
        }
    }
```

When I view the html in the div "#jsonFilterLength", is see that the length is increasing, so it appears to be storing additional data.  But the html in the div "#filterTest" only shows the data for the current text box I'm typing in, not what I would expect the entire json array to contain as I am trying to allow filtering on multiple text inputs simultaneously.

Regards,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/WQjsN/2/

Make sure you clear the jsonFilter variable on keyup function.

You can also modify the code so that it's shorter.

Eg.

```
for (var i = 0; i < _jsonFilter.length; i++) {
            var obj = _jsonFilter[i];
            $("#filterTest").append("Index: " + i + ", filterBy: " + obj.filterBy + ", filterValue: " + obj.filterValue + "<br /><br />");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Tom and ysrb.  I REALLY appreciated the jsfiddle.net example - didn't know about that!  It appears that the problem was that I wasn't clearing the jsonFilter variable.

Comment: Why do you 'return true' as a callback after the keyup?  I'm not monitoring that callback as part of anything.  Does it have something to do with default callbacks/event listeners in jQuery?

Comment: ysrb - Is that object notation already considered json and ready to be sent via ajax, or do I still have to 'stringify' it with json2.js?

Comment: Yes you can pass in the object in $.ajax.
bodyContent = $.ajax({
      url: "script.php",
      global: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: (jsonFilter),
      dataType: "html", //Change to json if the return type is json
      async:false,
      success: function(msg){
         alert(msg);
      }
   }
).responseText;

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you're doing exactly but to build / parse json I'd recomend you use Douglas Crockford's [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library.

So basically you'd build up a Javascript object to store the data you want to post up then call:

var jsonToPostToTheServer = JSON.stringify(myDataObjectToPostToTheServer);

PS at any point you say "I've added a global object" you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Tom - I'm no programming wizard, but there are times when a global variable is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if I were you I'd use an in- browser debugger to look at the content of your array/object. Try the built in stuff in IE (via the F12 key) or firebug in firefox, you can easily set breakpoints of JavaScript code and look at what is happening.

As for your json stuff, you should be able to just jsonify your array/object in one go at the point you want to call the Ajax function. So you just need to concentrate of building up the array/object for now

Comment: Antony - thanks for the help.  I do use firebug, and I'm getting better at it every day.  The problem with it, though, is that I can't use it to see data added dynamically into a div via an ajax call - unless there's a setting I'm not familiar with?

Comment: You should be able to inspect the content of any HTML element with any of the main browser debugger tools. Although I think also posting the HTML will help us all see what is going on.